# Passing data parameters on SSRS using snowflake datasoruce

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, parameter-passing, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using `snowflake` as a datasource for an `ssrs` report. I am trying to pass a parameter by adding my query as an expr.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
="select * from "Snowflake"."Past"."Customer"
where cast("startdate" as date)  = '" Parameters!mydate.Value"';"
```

when I am trying to `Refresh Fields` nothing is being populated and infact I am getting the error `Customers data has no fields`

also when I try to click on `Run` I am getting the error `[BC30205] End of statement expected`.

Can someone help?

Used the below link as reference to passing parameters:
https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00007DAa4MSAT/has-anyone-use-snowflake-as-datasource-for-mssql-ssrs-report-if-you-do-how-to-pass-a-vaiable-to-snowsql-from-ssrs

Thanks

Comment: I know nothing about Snowflake but the expression cannot be correct using double quotes like that. I would expect something more like `="select * from Snowflake.Past.Customer
where cast(startdate as date)  = '"  & Parameters!mydate.Value & "';"`

Comment: Hi @AlanSchofield, the double quotes is how the datasource has to be called otherwise it won't work :/

Comment: OK so that would mean you have to use pairs of double quotes, otherwise the expression is invalid.
`="select * from ""Snowflake"".Past"".""Customer"" where cast(""startdate"" as date)  = '"  & Parameters!mydate.Value & "';" ` . Also, you have cast to a `Date` type but compared to a string, I'm not sure if that is OK ? I know nothing about snowflake so it might be OK.

Comment: No problem. I'll add it as an answer so you can mark it as accepted, this will help others looking for similar solutions in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression is incorrect, if you need to use double quotes in your SLECT statment then you have to use pairs of double quotes like this.

```
="select * from ""Snowflake"".Past"".""Customer"" where cast(""startdate"" as date)  = '"  & Parameters!mydate.Value & "';"
```

Also, you have cast to a `Date` type but compared to a `string`, I'm not sure if that is OK ? I know nothing about snowflake so it might be OK